# How to detect warlock 'Create Thrall' effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Great Old One patron give the ability Create Thrall

> **Create Thrall**
>
> At 14th level, you gain the ability to infect a humanoid’s mind with the alien magic of your patron. You can use your action to touch
> an incapacitated humanoid. That creature is then charmed by you until
> a remove curse spell is cast on it, the charmed condition is removed
> from it, or you use this feature again.
>
> You can communicate telepathically with the charmed creature as long as the two of you are on the same plane of existence.

My question is simple: How can you detect this condition? Does a detect magic or true sight spell work? (The ability does not say it is magic, or even a spell). Any other method?

Comment: Are you looking for a method that will identify it as Create Thrall? Or just detect that there is an effect?

Comment: At least detect that a magic is present. In which case, dispel magic / remove curse can be casted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## *Detect Magic* will work

As you've quoted, the first sentence of **[Create Thrall](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheGreatOldOne)** specifically states it is magic(my emphasis):

> At 14th level, you gain the ability to infect a humanoid’s mind with the alien magic of your patron.

It is clear that this is magic, and should therefore be detected by *[detect magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic)*.

> For the duration, you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you.

### But what will it say?

Unfortunately, not much RAW, just that there is magic there. It'll be up to the players/DM to determine if anything more is disclosed and what that would be - or provide clues towards that if they don't want to outright disclose it in entirety.

Comment: I didn't even saw the 'alien magic' part before you spoke about it... I concentrated on the charmed part. Thanks !